What may not work in PyTorch when using qantized models?
I suppose not all the PyTorch tools and modules work with quantized (e.g. to int8) models. But what may not work and why?

Device and Operator Support


Quantization support is restricted to a subset of available operators, depending on the method being used, for a list of supported operators, please see the documentation at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html.
The set of available operators and the quantization numerics also depend on the backend being used to run quantized models. Currently quantized operators are supported only for CPU inference in the following backends: x86 and ARM.


Quantization


Quantized Operators/Modules. 
Quantized Operator are the operators that takes quantized Tensor as inputs, and outputs a quantized Tensor.
Quantized Modules are PyTorch Modules that performs quantized operations. They are typically defined for weighted operations like linear and conv.

